# How to save Visio macro as add-in

Tags: vba, visio

I wrote a macro in Visio, but noticed that I cannot add it to the quick-access toolbar. I assigned it to a keyboard shortcut, and I'd like to make it available in any Visio file which is opened.
With Word I just saved my macros as word add-ins, and made them available as global templates, however in Visio the options only show COM add-ins.

How can I make my macro available in every Visio file opened?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in Visio. A work-around is to save the macro into a stencil (you have to save the stencil in .vssm format) then if you always have this stencil open then the macro(s) will be available.

Comment: Hi Paul, I figured the way I was looking to do is it not possible from looking for a solution, so I hoped for a workaround. Having the template open with a different document makes the macro only show up under the template, so I have to drag it over or import it, which makes the whole point of trying to make repetitive actions more automated a bit less fulfilled. Thank you for the input!

Comment: So, as I said, put it in a stencil.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant, I thought of a template. I usually don't work on Visio, so the whole thing seems hugely unintuitive, and with almost no resources regarding the macro management issues. Is there any tutorial on how to assign stencils macros, then make these available in different docs?

Comment: Create a new stencil, open your template with the code, open the VBA editor, copy the VBA from template to stencil, save the stencil. Close all.